# Is it safe to vacuum seal shredded Parmesan?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, vacuum, botulism

I was trying to think of a way to more efficiently storing parmesan for quick access. I realized I could shred a batch and vacuum seal it in a jar to better preserve the flavor after shedding.

However, I am aware of the risk of botulism with high moisture content foods. However what I don't know is what the approximate moisture content is of parmesan cheese and whether or not that could pose a botulism risk.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have found that simply grating it into a Tupperware or similar container, placing the lid on it, and placing it in the freezer will hold the flavor well of grated Parmesan. It has been how I have always stored it when I bought it. Because of the grating, and the nature of cheese it has never taken long for it to thaw out if you are using it for things like a salad. A vacuum jar placing it in the refrigerator would probably work as well, just more work between each use as compared to just placing the container back into the freezer.

Comment: While interesting, your answer doesn't actually address the concerns in the question.

Comment: @razumny it is indeed not a direct answer, but StackExchange also allows answers which suggest better solutions to the OP's problem than the one the OP has decided to implement and is asking about. See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer, the point "Answer the question" for the policy.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is safe to freeze parmesan, and you can grate directly from frozen.

Comment: I wasn't planning on freezing it, however do you have a reference that documents the fact that freezing prevents botulism?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod - Oddly, I first read your question as regarding freezing too and even added comments I have since deleted. Not sure why two of us read the word "freezing" when what you wrote was something else entirely.  Just careless, I guess.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod That's not something you should need a reference for, really. [Proper freezing prevents all food safety issues](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer), not just botulism. Nothing grows at those temperatures, except maybe some pretty crazy extremophile bacteria that you're not going to find in your food.

Comment: @Jefromi I would say that proper freezing *holds the clock* on all food safety issues, because there are always people who are eager to understand *prevents* as a carte blanche for eating all kinds of already-unsafe-food after a pop in the freezer.

Comment: @rumtscho Very true. Maybe even more intuitive: it comes out as safe as it was when you put it in. (I meant "prevents...issues" as in "prevents issues due to time" not "prevents poison from being poisonous.")